# c# SQL how to join a list of strings to another WebApi accessing another database table

Tags: c#, sql, join, asp.net-web-api

I have an application where users must provide some kind of input for a request. One of the input fields is a specific document name that exists in another database. There is no relationship between the database used in the application and the database for the document name. This means, that wrong document names can be entered.

Now I want to make it possible to make an overview of all requests that do not have a valid document name, based on some kind of filter.

Let's say the user searchs for some requests with a choosen filter. 80.000 requests are found. Of these 80,000 requests, only the requests must be shown with a valid document number.

There are 2 WebApi's. The first WebApi is for the application itself. The other for interaction with de document database.

My question: Is there a fast way to only return the requests with a valid document name working with these 2 WebApi's? I think it's more a question of how to join a list of strings to another database table existing in another WebApi.

What I tried so far:

**Application WebApi:**

- Retrieving requests for filter
- Retrieving a list of all valid document numbers by passing all document numbers (myStringList) of the requests to the second WebApi
- Inner joining the list of requests with the document numbers.

This works good enough for small amount of request. In the application itself this problem is resolved by working with pagination. But an export to Excel function requires all data to be loaded without pagination.

**Document WebApi:**

These are some sql methods i tried to use. myStringList = the list of all document numbers from the requests.

The first method takes more than one minute to execute for 80.000 document numbers.
The second method takes 30 sec for 80.000 document numbers.

```
var commaSeparatedList = string.Join(",", myStringList.Select(item => "('" + item + "')"));
string sqlCommand =
    "  select DISTINCT [Name] " +
    "  from( " +
    "  SELECT * FROM(VALUES " + commaSeparatedList + ") as x(ID) " +
    "  ) x " +
    "  left join Table1 on x.ID = Table1 .Name";



var commaSeparatedList = string.Join(",", myStringList);
string sqlCommand =
  "DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), " +
  " @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)" +
  " SELECT @data = '" + commaSeparatedList + "' " +
  " set @delimiter = ','" +
  " DECLARE @textXML XML;" +
     " SELECT @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML);" +
     " declare @temp table(num nvarchar(max))" +
        " insert into @temp" +
        " SELECT T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data" +
        " FROM @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)" +
        " Select DISTINCT [Name] " +
        " FROM Table1 inner join @temp as x on x.num = Table1.[Name] ";
```

Comment: Create a new table the contains the document name and database.  Then check new table  before doing the long request.  This way you have backwards compatible and if somebody doesn't test new table then it is their faults if takes a long time to get nothing back because they are requesting from wrong database.

Comment: Ahh yes, the birth of an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Use EF with a contains query.  Otherwise use a proc with a table valued parameter or a proper xml query.